# Basic Authentication URL Handling

Tags: php, basic-authentication

We have a new b2b vendor that wants to use basic auth via URL.

They want to authenticate like this:

```
  //URL coming into our server
  http://usernametext:passwordtext@our.company.com/listener.php
```

How can I get the username and password from the URL via my listener.php script?

I have tried setting basic auth headers per the php man page but it pops up a login box, which is not what I need, since these are web services talking to each other, not people:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
     header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
     header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
     echo '<response><error>No username and password found</error></response>';
     exit;
 } else {

   //process request if username & password are legit

}
```

Comment: Basic http authentication relies on special entries in http header, so it's not compatible with your first requirement to pass username and password via URL. Just do not return 401 error, instead redirect to a dedicated page if not authorized.

Comment: Though this method is severely insecure (transferring username/password in cleartext) couldn't you use get variables? http://url.com/listener.php?username=USERNAME&pass=PASSWORD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all that offered solutions. Here is what solved this issue for me:

It was a server configuration issue. I needed to compile the [Apache extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apache.php) in my PHP. Once I did that, the $_SERVER array contained $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] and $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] values. Prior to this, those values were missing from the $_SERVER array

Answer (score 0):

Why not send the info via good old $_GET? Something like 
`http://our.company.com/listener.php?usr='me'&pswd='secret'`

Answer (score -1):

may be this could help:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
```

more detailed you can check on : [http-auth](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)

Update: If you dont need popup box (which is confirmation user+pass on non required auth site) simply add .htaccess on directory.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
```

Comment: Thanks but I already looked there and included a snippet in my question above